# Filling a *char[] with user input

Tags: c, pointers, char, segmentation-fault, scanf

Im am trying to implement the following c code:

```c
int row, col;
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col); 



    char *map[col];

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i ++){
        scanf("%s", map[i]);
    }
```

Where the user enters two numbers on the same line to declare the size of rows and columns of the array. Then the user will proceed to enter each row which will be stored. An example input would look like this:

```
10 12
oooooooooooo
oooooo.o.ooo
o.o.ooooooo.
o.o.o..o...o
o.ooo.oo.o.o
o...oooo.o.o
.......o.o.o
o.o.o.oo.o.o
ooooooooo..o
o...oooooo.o
```

But when I run my code I get a segmentation fault. Any suggestions?

**I am not able to use char map[][] as other functions in the program use *char[].**

Comment: That snippet will not "run". It will not even compile. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I can assure you that the first snipet compiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I run my code I get a segmentation fault.

It's because the array `map` is uninitialized (which is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

Initialize it with calls for `malloc()` or `calloc()` for each of the pointers in the `map` array. or just use a VLA which also defines the rows: `char map[row][col];`.

If you decide to use VLAs, be aware that they may not work for large size of `row` and `col` as they are allocated on automatic storage (aka "stack") and are only optional feature since C11.

Comment: Can you give me the code to get it to work with my program?

Comment: There's not much else to provide code. VLA usage is straightforward and you should be able to find plenty of examples on how to use `malloc()` by googling (or reading your textbook).